# Log Selection of DropDownList in Text File

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, streamwriter

I am trying to log the selection a user makes when they select a choice from a dropdownlist. I have autopostback enabled and when a user selects a choice it updates content on the page. I also have a search button for people who like to click search. I know I need to use the SelectedIndexChanged

```
 protected void CategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("selectordata/results.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(//Write Data Here);
        sw.Close();
        }
```

My first question is how do I write what Selection they just made in the SelectedIndexChanged. I cant call CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue can I?

Secondly Is there any way I can keep track of if it is the same user. Mean Idealy in my text file I would like to store it like this

> 8/12/2011 10:56 AM SESSIONID(or something) Selected Category #1
>   8/12/2011 10:57 AM SAME SESSIONID Selected Product #2

Can this be done easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the selected index, you can retrieve the item from the collection or just the selected value:

```
 string value = myDropDownList.SelectedValue;
 ListItem item = myDropDownList.Items[myDropDownList.SelectedIndex];
```

If you need to find the specific user's session Id, you can grab that from your session object (assuming you are using Microsoft's default Session):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

Comment: Whats the best way to deal with the chance that two people may try to write to the file at the same time? wouldn't that cause an access denied error?

Answer (score 0):

you can call DropDownList.SelectedValue and you can also store your userId is some sort of session and retrieve using Session["key"].